# How to edit "Index of/" on website

Tags: html, css, web, ftp, indexing

Recently I have been trying to achieve a navigation for my website that can view files and folders and go up one directory etc...

I have realised that if I make a folder on my website FTP server and then within that folder I put a whole lot of other folders or files it will list them all in an "Index of/ " (as long as there is no "index.html" or similar named file)

Please use this as an example:
http://ysk.co.za/test/

So now I would like to change the CSS of that page that indexes the files and folders, and possibly edit it in other ways.

Is it possible to do so? If not is there an alternative to achieve similar results.

Answers would be much appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: Make an `index.php` or whatever that dynamically lists all the files/folders, add your own CSS.

Comment: @thirtydot how would you make that `index.php` dynamically list all files and folders?

Comment: Google it. If you can't find what you're looking for, let me know and I'll point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing there is just a directory listing on the web server.  Since you haven't written a page (using some sort of server-side technology like PHP, JSP, etc.) that actually lists the directory structure, you aren't going to be able to extend the functionality of the page or change the appearance using only CSS.